# Let's start where we stopped

Tags: phrase-usage

Is this phrase idiomatic?

> "Let's start where we stopped"

If it isn't then what is the right phrase?

Comment: FumbleFinger's answer below immediately came to mind. Have you also noticed Microsoft Word suggesting "continue where you left off" when reopening a document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't really imagine many people using OP's example. The most common thing would probably be...

> ***Let's pick up where we left off***

That's definition 7 in [macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pick-up)

> **to pick up** - *to start something again, **from the point where you stopped*** (italics mine)
>    Example: *He seems to think that we can get back together and just pick up where we left off.*

...plus this definition from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave-off-sth-doing-sth)...

> **to leave off (sth/doing sth)** - *to stop, or to stop doing something*
>    Example: *This novel begins where the other one leaves off.*

Comment: The definition itself (7 in macmillandictionary) uses start and stop. Could you please explain the difference between pick up/left off and start/stop? Do you fell that they have some subtle difference in usage?

Comment: In a word, ***no**!* - for the contexts we're talking about here, which involve pausing / suspending / interrupting some kind of "continuous process". Except to note that ***to pick up*** (and to a lesser extent, ***to leave off***) are *slightly* more "informal" than ***start / stop***. And all these verb forms have many *other* senses in different contexts, where they're not at all interchangeable.